# Using Pipe on two related variables in Angular ngModel

Tags: angular

I have two inputs that take temps like this: one in Fahrenheit and another in Celcius. If the user enters a number in C, the input of F should be filled with the proper conversion in Fahrenheit and vice versa. **But the problem is when I want to use a pipe to show the result with 1 decimal number.**
There are many solutions with one input. But I could not find any way to implement it with two inputs.

HTML file:

```
  <section>
    <label>Celsius: </label>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="tempC | number:'1.0-1" (ngModelChange)="modelChangedC()"/>
  </section>

  <section >
      <label>Fahrenheit: </label>
      <input type="number"  [ngModel]="tempF | number:'1.0-1" (ngModelChange)="modelChangedF()"/>
  </section>
```

typescript file:

```
  tempF: number = 0;
  tempC: number = 0;
   
  modelChangedC() {
    this.tempF = this.tempC*9/5 + 32;
  }

  modelChangedF() {
    this.tempC = (this.tempF - 32) * 5/9;
  }
```

Comment: It is a little unclear, what problem are you seeing when you use the number pipe?

Comment: When I put for example 1 in C input, in another input(F) shows 1 too and it never changes even if change value in C input again

Comment: gotcha. I have a solution, I will write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `ngModel` to two way bind it you need to use the syntax `[(ngModel)]` but you can't do that because you are using a pipe. To get around this you need to capture the `$event` that comes from the `ngModelChange` emission. This can be done as follows

HTML:

```
  <section>
    <label>Celsius: </label>
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="tempC | number:'1.0-1'" (ngModelChange)="modelChangedC($event)"/>
  </section>

  <section >
      <label>Fahrenheit: </label>
      <input type="number"  [ngModel]="tempF | number:'1.0-1'" (ngModelChange)="modelChangedF($event)"/>
  </section>
```

TS:

```
  tempC = 0;
  tempF = 0;

  modelChangedC(ev) {
    this.tempC = ev;
    this.tempF = this.tempC*9/5 + 32;
  }

  modelChangedF(ev) {
    this.tempF = ev;
    this.tempC = (this.tempF - 32) * 5/9;
  }
```

here is working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ynmzbi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Also note that you are missing the closing single quote in your pipe declaration. It should be `"tempC | number:'1.0-1'"` not `"tempC | number:'1.0-1"`

Comment: Thanks. I wrote the solution without pipe the challenging part was using pipe! Is it ok to ask a vote up to my question?